# How should I deal with external dependencies in my functions when writing unit tests?

Tags: testing

The following function iterates through the names of directories in the file system, and if they are not in there already, adds these names as records to a database table. (Please note this question applies to most languages).

```
def find_new_dirs():
    dirs_listed_in_db = get_dirs_in_db()

    new_dirs = []
    for dir in get_directories_in_our_path():
        if dir not in dirs_listed_in_db:
            new_dirs.append(dir)

    return new_dirs
```

I want to write a unit test for this function. However, the function has a dependency on an external component - a database. So how should I write this test?

I assume I should 'mock out' the database. Does this mean I should take the function `get_dirs_in_db` as a parameter, like so?

```
def find_new_dirs(get_dirs_in_db):
    dirs_listed_in_db = get_dirs_in_db()

    new_dirs = []
    for dir in get_directories_in_our_path():
        if dir not in dirs_listed_in_db:
            new_dirs.append(dir)

    return new_dirs
```

Or possibly like so?

```
def find_new_dirs(db):
    dirs_listed_in_db = db.get_dirs()

    new_dirs = []
    for dir in get_directories_in_our_path():
        if dir not in dirs_listed_in_db:
            new_dirs.append(dir)

    return new_dirs
```

Or should I take a different approach?

Also, should I design my whole project this way from the start? Or should I refactor them to this design when the need arises when writing tests?

Comment: Besides what I mentioned in the answer, you might want to Google "solid principles" and also search for that term on YouTube.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing is called **dependency injection** and yes, it is a common way of writing testable code. The second method you outlined (where you would pass in the db) is probably more common. Also, you can have the `db` parameter to your function take a default value so you are able to only specify the mock db in testing cases.

Whether to write your code that way at the outset or modify it later would be a matter of opinion, but if you adhere to the **Test-driven development** (TDD) methodology then you would write your tests before your code-under-test anyway.

There are other ways to deal with this problem, but you're asking a  broad question at that point.

Answer (score 1):

I take it these code fragments are python, which I'm not familiar with, but in any case this looks like the methods are detached from any stateful object and I'm not sure if that's idiomatic python or simply your design.

In an OOD you'd want an object that holds a data access object in its state (similar to your 2nd version) and mock that object for tests. You'd also want to mock the `get_directories_our_path` part.

As for *when* this design should be done - as the first step before creating the first code file. You should use dependency injection throughout your code. This will aid in testing as well as decoupling and increased reusability of your classes.